# How can I achieve a paginated join, with the first page returned quickly?

Tags: postgresql, bigdata, olap

I am looking to join multiple big tables in the OLAP layer to power the UI. Since the tables are really large, response for each join query takes too long. I want to get results in less than 3 seconds. But the catch is I don't want the entire joined data at once because I am only displaying a small subset of the result in the UI at any particular point. Only user interaction would require me to show the next subset of the result.

I am looking for a strategy to create a system where I can perform the same join queries, but initially only a small subset is joined and used for powering the UI. Meanwhile, the rest of the smaller subsets of data is joined in the background and that gets pulled into the UI when required. Is this the right way to approach this problem, where I have to perform really big joins? If so, how can I design such a system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `WITH HOLD` cursor:

```
START TRANSACTION;

DECLARE c CURSOR WITH HOLD FOR SELECT /* big query */;

FETCH 50 FROM c;

COMMIT;
```

The `COMMIT` will take a long time, as it materializes the whole result set, but the `FETCH 50` can be reasonably fast (or not, depending on the query).

You can then continue fetching from the cursor. **Don't forget to close the cursor when you are done:**

```
CLOSE c;
```

Comment: Will using cursor wait for the all the tables to join and just fetch the required number of rows, or will it join a subset of the data and returns its results immediately?

Comment: The first `FETCH` will return the first rows as soon as it can. The `COMMIT` will compute the complete result set.

Comment: How would I need to modify this if I need the entire result of the query as subsequent pages only?

Comment: That's what my answer provides, doesn't it?

Comment: As you said, `COMMIT` will materialise the entire result. But I don't need to fetch the entire result at any point. I just need it in batches of a certain number of rows. In that case, I wouldn't need to use COMMIT, right?

Comment: You need to use `COMMIT`, because you cannot leave a transaction open during a user interaction. It will cause problems for your database. There is no good way to avoid the `COMMIT`.

Comment: Is there any way to close a transaction without using commit?

Comment: You cannot successfully close a transaction other than with `COMMIT`.